# React component with Apollo graphQL useQuery extra renders

Tags: reactjs, react-apollo

I have the following simple component:

```
import React from 'react';
import { useQuery, gql } from '@apollo/client';

const TEST= gql`
 query TEST{
   test
 }
`

const Test = () => {
  const { loading, error, data } = useQuery(TEST);
  console.log('rendering...');
  return <div>test</div>
};

export default Test;
```

When I check the console, I see `rendering...` *six* times. When I blank out the call to `useQuery` I see only *one* `rendering...`

can somebody help me solve the mystery? thanks!